# Synchronous POST to endpoint doesn't post data - java

Tags: java, apache, post, json

I am trying to send synchronous POST to an endpoint like following:

But it seems my httpClinet is posting a blank data. What am I doing wrong here?

Here is httpClinetPost postTo implementation:

```
public static String postTo(String stringToPass) 
{
   HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost(some url);
    request.setEntity(new ByteArrayEntity(stringToPassing);
    HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
    int res = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

    if (res == 401) {
        throw new IOException(res);
    } else if (res != 200) {
        throw new IOException(res);
    }

    String responseString = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: How do you know it's posting blank data?

Comment: I put a log for "autoStackRep" in testPost and it was null.